# Get filename from url without timestamp and with out file name extension - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

From below different urls i need file name only

> URL 1 = uploads/4/jobs/2017-02-15-05-17-05pmThe_Wolf_of_Wall_Street_-_Jordan_Belfort.pdf
>   URL 2 = uploads/4/jobs/2017-02-15-05-17-05ammaster.jpg

What I need is

```
Result1 = The_Wolf_of_Wall_Street_-_Jordan_Belfort
Result2 = master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
let name  = "uploads/4/jobs/2017-02-15-05-17-05pmThe_Wolf_of_Wall_Street_-_Jordan_Belfort.pdf"
var names = name.components(separatedBy: "/")
let lastComponent = names[names.count - 1]

var nameOfFile:String = ""
let pm = lastComponent.components(separatedBy: "pm")
let am = lastComponent.components(separatedBy: "am")
if(pm.count > 1){
    nameOfFile = pm[1]
} else if(am.count > 1){
    nameOfFile = am[1]
}
print(nameOfFile)
```

Comment: What if file name contains `2017-02-15-05-17-05pmAbc-am.pdf` then?

Comment: you can remove the last path component or by using :
var fileNameComponents = filename.components(separatedBy: ".") 
let  fileNameOnly =  fileNameComponents[0]

Answer (score 1):

If your url will always follow start naming format.

```
  let urlStr = "uploads/4/jobs/2017-02-15-05-17-05pmThe_Wolf_of_Wall_Street_-_Jordan_Belfort.pdf"
  let indexStart = urlStr.index(urlStr.startIndex, offsetBy: +36)
  let str = urlStr.substring(from: indexStart )
  let indexEnd = str.index(str.endIndex, offsetBy: -4)
  let name = str.substring(to: indexEnd )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code for Objective-C

```
NSString* string = @"uploads/4/jobs/2017-02-15-05-17-05pmThe_Wolf_of_Wall_Street_-_Jordan_Belfort.pdf";

NSArray* array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString* lastElement = [array lastObject];

NSArray* finalArrayForPM = [lastElement componentsSeparatedByString:@"pm"];
NSArray* finalArrayForAM = [lastElement componentsSeparatedByString:@"am"];
if (finalArrayForPM.count > 1) {
    NSString* fileName = [[finalArrayForPM lastObject] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSLog(@"The fileName is %@",fileName);
} else if (finalArrayForAM.count > 1) {
    NSString* fileName = [[finalArrayForAM lastObject] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSLog(@"The fileName is %@",fileName);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if file name contains `2017-02-15-05-17-05pmAbc-am.pdf` then?